# MVC unit of work and repository not working for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, asp.net-web-api, unit-of-work

I have a web api set up to get companies from a data base.

```
namespace Bloginect.Controllers
{

public abstract class ApiControlerBase : ApiController
{
    protected BloginectUow Uow { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyController : ApiControlerBase
{
    // Dependancy set up with Ninject
    public CompanyController(BloginectUow uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
    }

    // GET api/company
    public IEnumerable<Company> Get()
    {     
        *-------- Uow.companies is null here ----------*
        return Uow.companies.GetCompanies();
    }
}
}
```

I am getting a null exception for companies on the line

```
return Uow.companies.GetCompanies();
```

The unit of work class holds a company repository and it is set up as follows

```
namespace Bloginect.Data
{
public class BloginectUow : IDisposable
{
    private BloginectDbContext DbContext = new BloginectDbContext();
    public ICompanyRepository companies { get; set; }      

    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();            
    }        

}
}
```

The company repository interfaceis set up as follows

```
public interface ICompanyRepository : IRepository<Company>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets companies
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies();
    }

IRepository<Company>
```

is just a standard repository with crud operations

Can anyone see a problem and why is the `ICompanyRepository` not getting initiated.

Comment: In `BloginectUow`, where did you instance your `companies` property?

Comment: Can you instantiate an interface?

Comment: In fact, with a concrete type of this interface.. where did you initialize it?

Comment: How would I set that up? I'm not really sure.

Comment: Did you implement this interface in a class?

Comment: That's the reason. You need to implement a concret type of the `interface` and initialize it on your Unit of Work. If you don't do this, you will get a exception. I will add a answer.

Comment: Is this normal even if I will have many interfaces? All implemented in the one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your repository. Take a look at the samples how could you do this:

1º Solution - Not Generic implementation... you can do some specific and complex queries on this scenario for each entity.

```
public class BloginectUow : IDisposable
{
    private BloginectDbContext DbContext = new BloginectDbContext();

    public ICompanyRepository Companies { get; set; }      

    // constructor
    public BloginectUow()
    {
        // initialize your repository..
        Companies = new CompanyRepository();
    }

    /// methods...
}
```

In this case you have to have a class to implement your `ICompanyRepository` interface:

```
public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository {

   // methods of the interface to data access... from entity framework or nhibernate or ado.net or whatever...

}
```

2º Solution - Or, you could use an generic repository:

```
public class BloginectUow : IDisposable
{
    private BloginectDbContext DbContext = new BloginectDbContext();

    public IRepository<Company> Companies { get; set; }      

    // constructor
    public BloginectUow()
    {
        // initialize your repository with a generic implementation..
        Companies = new Repository<Company>();
    }

    /// methods...
}
```

In the second case, you have to have a `Repository<T>` class (which need to have CRUD operations... for sample) and use a interface of this class on your `UnitOfWork`.

Doing this way, you will get a generic implementation of your DataAccess but you could not to do complex queries when you need. If you need to do complex queries I would recommend you to get a single implementation of Repository for each entity, inherits if from a generic repository and implement method to do complex queries, that's a good pratice.